# PHP variable from multiple MySQL lines of a column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a variable in PHP from several MySQL lines in a column. My current code:

```
$prio1 = "50";

$sql = "SELECT ID FROM rechte WHERE prio<=$prio1";
$prios = $conn->query($sql);

while($prios2 = mysqli_fetch_array($prios))
{
    $abfrage1 = $prios2[0];
}
```

what should come out = "1,5"
what comes out = "5"

Comment: What do you get if your put the same query in MySQL?

Comment: Question is not very clear. I can only assume you mean this query should return 2 IDs... 1 and 5. If that is the case, in this example `$abfrage1` is being overwritten. For example, replace `$abfrage1 = $prios2[0];` with `echo $prios2[0].'<br/>';`.

Comment: @Dour High Arch My MySQL 

SELECT ID FROM rechte WHERE prio<=50


ID 
1 
5

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @tadman No need to use prepared statement unless `$prio1` represents user input. In fact, if that's the case it's BETTER not to prepare.

Comment: @PhillipWeber No, you prepare **everything** that's data. It might not be user input today, but you can't say for sure about the future, and if that day comes and someone inadvertently wires that up to a `$_GET` parameter, then you have a huge problem. Prepared statements make it extremely obvious that things are done correctly, you can audit them in a snap. Interpolated vriables like that are always a liability and should be removed whenever possible. There's no excuse here, at all. Preparing it makes it safe, guaranteed.

Comment: @tadman If someone changes it to take user input, then they should be responsible to convert to prepared statement. Prepare statements take 2 trips to the DB and twice as long to execute in this simple case. What I recommend in this case is using const for literals i.e. `const PRIO1 = 50;`. This will assure it not take user input in the future as well AND keep things fast.

Comment: @tadman I should add, if it does take user input, and expects integer... why not use signature `function(int $prio1 = PRIO_DEFAULT){/* query */}`, boom - safe AND efficient.

Comment: `$abfrage1` is being rewritten in each iteration of the while loop. Use `$abfrage1[] = $prios2[0];` if you want to save the values in an array.

Comment: @PhillipWeber Not safe, not "efficient". This is how huge mistakes happen. Use placeholder values. I'm not sure why you're choosing to die on this hill, it's absurd. It's like "re-using needles several times is just fine!" or "uncooked chicken is totally harmless!" The number one reason to use placeholder values is you must make *several* mistakes before something bad happens, whereas the injection approach means a single mistake can completely undo you.

Comment: @tadman I respectfully disagree, if I can 100% ensure my params are good without using prepares, (in most cases) I will not use them-- especially for int vals. Also, I limit what the db user can actually do - no deletes and if possible not even updates (immutable data). You can even make a separate user for implicit deletes/updates. Prepared statements were designed for making multiple of the same queries with different params. While I agree in many cases you should use prepare for safety, sometimes it is an absolute waste.

Comment: @PhillipWeber Placeholder vlaues are for *separating data from query* which is extremely important under all circumstances, not your arbitrarily narrow defined circumstances that have a *huge* number of caveats. Prepared statements have additional benefits beyond data separation, so there's really no reason to not use them. You're advocating the "SQL speed holes" approach, and this is reckless at best and [catastrophic in its worst form](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: @PhillipWeber Where there's room for error, error will occur. With placeholder values you really can't screw things up. With interpolation you can and will. There's no going back from a database breach. There's no room for half-measures here. Do it properly the first time. Above all, be professional about this. We need to have standards, and we need to stick to them. If software engineering had a code like plumbing or electrical did, in it would be the strict requirement to use placeholder values. What you do on your own is your concern, but don't advocate dangerous practices.

Comment: @tadman there are many many well tested libraries that emulate prepared statements without the extra call to the db. Would you then advocate not using them?

Comment: @PhillipWeber Emulation is fine, those libraries are well-tested and proven to work correctly. If they're not fine, someone is bound to open up an issue and get it resolved, or maybe file a CVE if it's bad. It's less likely to impact you because the community will fix it first, it's not your job. With your "it's an int so it's *probably okay*" code, the first one to find out about a vulnerability will be you... *after* it's exploited... *if* you're lucky.

Comment: @tadman Ok good, you are a reasonable man. Kudos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the results in an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them, like so:

```
$prio1 = "50";

$query = "SELECT ID FROM rechte WHERE prio <= ?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("i", $prio1);
$result = $statement->execute();

$abfrage = [];
while($prios2 = $result->fetch_array($prios))
{
    $abfrage[] = $prios2[0];
}

$abfrage1 = implode(",", $abfrage);
```

Now `$abfrage1` should contain all the values.

Ah, please read up on [SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). It is good practice to **always** use prepared statements when you use a PHP variable in your query. This will be your best defence against SQL-injection. Don't think that you know that `$prio1` is an internal number and will never come from the user. Eventhough that might be true now, it might not be true in the future.

Comment: The advisory is warranted, but would take less time to warn about SQL injection than to fix it.

Comment: Tahnk for your Help 100% Works

Comment: @tadman: That was my idea as well, fixed it... Didn't even look at that bit at first... sorry...